# How to change the Date format in crystel report

Tags: crystal-reports, inet

Can anybody tell me how to change the date format in crystal report.

this is my coding.

FormulaField for_date_of_birth = fields.addFormulaField("f_date_of_birth","Totext({hr_rpt_employee.date_of_birth}) = \"1900-01-01\"",FormulaField.FORMULA_PROPERTY);

here i want MM/DD/YYYY format but is coming like YYYY/MM/DD formarmat

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the crystal report Editor ? in this case you can find everything by right click on the text object and edit the date format.

Comment: No I am not using crystal report Editor.In Jsp file only i written above mention code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Totext` with an optional parameter, a string that specifying how to format the string representation. The default depends on the system locale.

```
Totext({hr_rpt_employee.date_of_birth}, "MM/dd/yyyy" )
```

Example

```
ToText( CurrentDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

output:  `01/11/2013`

Answer (score 0):

select column and right click then pic date format[image]